# Jitsi: How to hide right side bar (participants) in the app and mobile browser?

Tags: streaming

In Jitsi (add tag for me please), on desktop (browser, both Firefox and Chrome), I can hide the right panel (that shows all the participants) by clicking on the ">" arrow:

[image]

[image]

But I can't seem to find any such option in either the (mobile) app or mobile browser. (Or am I missing something?)

Mobile browser (Firefox, Android):

[image]

(Mobile) app (Android):

[image]

Comment: Isnt this something that you should ask Jitsi support, because it looks like thats how they have designed it?